# how to avoid repeating linear regression procedures when adding new points

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-regression

I know how to do to do regression on a set of N samples. However, my project is about doing the linear regression of the first 2, 3, 4 ... k, k+1, ... N samples respectively. Instead of repeating the same procedure when adding a new sample, is there a faster method that I can use the previous result (or intermediate results) to solve the regression after adding a new point? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear least squares method coefficients of approximation line are calculated using these formulas:

```
a = (N * Sum(Xi*Yi) - Sum(Xi)*Sum(Yi)) / (n * Sum(Xi^2) - (Sum(Xi))^2)
b = (Sum(Yi) - a * Sum(Xi)) / N
```

So you can store the values of Nth sums

```
Sum(Xi*Yi)
Sum(Xi)
Sum(Yi)
Sum(Xi^2)
```

and update them at (N+1)th step.

```
Sum(Xi)[N+1] = Sum(Xi)[N] + X(N+1)
Sum(Xi*Yi)[N+1] = Sum(Xi*Yi)[N] + X(N+1)*Y(N+1)
```

and so on, and calculate new coefficients values.

Note: such algorithms are called 'running' or 'online' - see [analog for std deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm)